Generating a table with php from sql records
I want to generate a list in pdf of the passengers on a bus ride.
My problem is, that in every second cell on the right side, there is the same person from the first cell in every row.

And i want to order them with "ut_utasok_ules_pozicio" column. This means the seat number on the bus.
My code is:
`$html .= '';
    while($aa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($adat))
    {
        $html .= '<tr>
                    <td>'.$aa['ut_utasok_ules_pozicio'] . '. ' . $aa['utas_nev'] . '</td>
                    <td>'.$aa['ut_utasok_ules_pozicio'] . '. ' . $aa['utas_nev'] . '</td>
                 </tr>';
    }
    
    $html .= '</table>';`

I tried modify my sql query, but i think the problem isnt there.

You printed both fields in each table cell. Surely you can see this from looking at the code just for a moment? Both lines are identical. That's why the output is identical. But you didn't actually say what the desired output was, instead of that.

This question can surely be regarded as caused by typo / not reproducible

[from comments) "First cell, first person with his seat number. Second cell, second person, with the seat number" - if you want that, then you need to fetch data from two records, to create one such table row. Either you add a second mysqli_fetch_assoc within the loop (which might return null, in which case you'd need to leave the second cell blank), or you implement a logic to output one record's values into one cell, and decide whether you need to close the current row and open a new one, or just output the next cell.

Based on your comments, I've revised my answer to better address your needs.
You want to display two records per row, like this:
+-------------+-------------+
| #1 Person 1 | #2 Person 2 |
+-------------+-------------+
| #3 Person 3 | #4 Person 4 |
+-------------+-------------+
| #5 Person 5 |  and so on  |
+-------------+-------------+

One straightforward way to achieve this is to use mysqli_fetch_assoc twice within the same loop, as shown below:
while ($aa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($adat)) {
    // Fetch the next record
    $ab = mysqli_fetch_assoc($adat);
    /**
     * At this point, you have an odd-numbered
     * record in $aa and the following even-numbered
     * record in $ab.
     * Each iteration will process $aa and possibly $ab records.
     */

     // Start row
    $html .= '<tr>';

    // Print first cell in row
    $html .= '<td>' . $aa['ut_utasok_ules_pozicio'] . '. ' . $aa['utas_nev'] . '</td>';
    
    // Check if the second record exists
    if ($ab) {
        // Print second cell in row, if record exists
        $html .= '<td>' . $ab['ut_utasok_ules_pozicio'] . '. ' . $ab['utas_nev'] . '</td>';
    } else {
        // Insert an empty cell if there is no second record
        $html .= '<td></td>';
    }
    // Close row        
    $html .= '</tr>';
}

This method is the simplest way to print two different records per row.
I leave my original answer below for reference.
===================================
I used Google Translate to understand your fields; it suggests that "utas név" is Hungarian for "passenger name."
In your code, you have two identical cells with identical data:
$html .= '<tr>
                <td>'.$aa['ut_utasok_ules_pozicio'] . '. ' . $aa['utas_nev'] . '</td>
                <td>'.$aa['ut_utasok_ules_pozicio'] . '. ' . $aa['utas_nev'] . '</td>
             </tr>';

This is why you see the same content in both cells.
I think you might want to display the seat number in the first cell and the passenger name in the second cell, like this:
$html .= '<tr>
                    <td>'. $aa['ut_utasok_ules_pozicio'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $aa['utas_nev'] . '</td>
                 </tr>';

Regarding your comment:

i want to order them with "ut_utasok_ules_pozicio" column

it seems your records are already sorted, as the numbers from 1 to 4 appear in the correct order.
Please consider reviewing the basics of HTML. You can start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

I'm sure you want to display the number on the left and the name on the right. I see that PHP can retrieve data from the database correctly, it just needs adjustments in the PHP code.
<table>
    <?php while($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $d['ut_utasok_ules_pozicio']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $d['utas_nev']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>

As you can see from the code above, I have organized the code you created to make it easier to read, and in the future, if there is a need for corrections, it will be easier to fix.

No. First cell, first person with his seat number. Second cell, second person, with the seat number, order the rows by the seat number.

You wrote your question incompletely, so I apologize if my answer does not match what you were looking for.

@nagyaaa2000 This is why you should always post an example of the expected results, so that there is no confusion. People answered your question based on what they thought you asked for. But you asked in a way that was not totally clear. You really need to edit your question to improve it.
